# criteria for both GPS and network

Tags: android, gps, location

I would like to know how can I get location from the best provider
do I have to make two separate criteria 1 for the GPS and 1 for the network or is there a way to put them all together ?
this is my code when I add the COARSE criteria the GPS does not go on (no GPS flashing logo on the top of the screen) and when I use the FINE criteria I dont get any thing from the network.......so do I have to write criteria for both and switch between them for what ever is available or can they both be in the same criteria ?
because I have the "getBestProvider(criteria, true);" in my code so it should get the location from the best provider....right..??!

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
//// criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

Comment: Why are you even calling `setAccuracy()`, since apparently you are willing to accept any accuracy?

Comment: i want the accuracy but at some locations like in tunnels or around tall buildings the only location you can get is from a network...

Answer (score 1):

Using a `getBestProvider` with `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE` will never return the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`, even though wifi position is usually quite accurate.

In my application, I use `getProviders` to get **all** providers matching my criteria, then add the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` if it is activated and not yet in the list.

Then I launch a `requestLocationUpdates` for each of these providers, making sure to call `removeUpdates` when I get a location accurate enough.

This way, if the location provided by the network is accurate enough, the gps provider will be turned off

Answer (score 0):

@nicopico getBestProvider with Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE can return the NETWORK_PROVIDER if gps is not enabled
i use the following code in my app

```
public void getLocation() {
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

//        boolean network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // Showing status
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available
            Log.e(TAG, "getLocation fired Google Play Services are not available");

           mHandler.post(new UiToastCommunicaton(context.getApplicationContext(),
                   context.getResources().getString(R.string.gpserv_notfound)));
        }

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(IntentService.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {//check if network location provider context on
            Log.e(TAG, "network location provider not enabled");
        } else {
            criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            //criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            // Getting the name of the best provider
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Check provider exists then request for location
            if (provider != null) {
                requestLocation(locationManager, provider);
            } else {
                //start wifi, gps, or tell user to do so
            }

        }
    }
public void requestLocation(LocationManager locationManager, String provider) {
Log.e(TAG, "requestLocation fired getting location now");

if (provider != null) {

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
} else {
    //tell user what has happened
}
}
```

this code is in a class that implements locationListener
you can edit this line

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
```

to reflect your implementation of locationListener